# Current Candle Arithmetic in Pine Version#4

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

What is the standard way to detect change within the current candle.

Specifically, is there a built in function, or commonly used way to determine when the current candle goes from -ve to +ve (red to green) 'in the moment'

I had a look at .rising function, crossover(open), and I'm wondering how this is most commonly expressed in pine. Many Thanks.

Comment: I know this can be achieved externally by polling ohlc data, say every n seconds. but a clean pine expression may save me from this. cheers.